# Given that the first child draws $10\$$ from his envelope, what is the probability that the second child has an envelope that contains a 20$ note?

Tags: probability, statistics

Three children each receive an envelope from their grandparents. It is known that each envelope contains three banknotes and that in the three envelopes together there are two $5\$$ notes, four $10\$$ notes and three $20\$$ notes. The first child opens his envelope and the first note that he draws from it is a $10\$$ bill. What is now the probability that the second child has a $20$$ note in his envelope?

---

I have difficulty thinking about this question as it seems very complex. My intuition tells me that probably conditional probabilities are involved and maybe even Bayes' rule. However, besides that, I have no clue where to start. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Presumably, you know that the three bills are chosen at random for each child.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I think that is what we may assume.

Comment: It's a conditional probability I think?

Comment: Consider the three possible cases: The first child got no 20, got one 20, and got two 20s.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ok, that makes sense. Still though, don't I need to include the fact that already a 10 is drawn (because this reduces the chance of drawing a 20 for the first child)?

Comment: Yes, $1/3$ of the time the first child got a single $20$, he'd have pulled that. So you can only count $2/3$ of those instances. @rbm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the bills as distinct (they have serial numbers). Imagine that the grandparents took the $9$ bills, arranged them in order at random, and slipped them into envelopes, *preserving order*. That gives $9!$ equally likely permutations. But $9!$ will not appear in our solution, since we want to avoid explicit use of conditional probability.

The top bill in the first child's envelope is a $10$. Without loss of generality it is the $10$ with lowest serial number. That leaves $8!$ equally likely permutations.

How many of these leave the second child sad because she got no $20$'s? There are $(5)(4)(3)$ ways that non-$20$'s can be in her envelope (recall that we are counting order). And the remaining $5$ bills can be in any of $5!$ orders. Thus the probability that the second child receives no $20$'s is $(5)(4)(3)(5!)/8!$. This is $\frac{5}{28}$. The probability she gets at least one $20$ is $\frac{23}{28}$.

**Remark:** There are many other ways to solve the problem. Here is one that could be thought simpler.   We use a slightly different but equivalent model. After placing the "top" bill in the first  envelope, the grandparents **choose** $3$ of the remaining bills to place in the second envelope.

**Given** that the top bill was the $10$ dollar bill with lowest serial number, there are $\binom{8}{3}$ ways to choose $3$ bills from the rest. And there are $\binom{5}{3}$ ways of choosing $3$ non-$20$'s. So the (conditional) probability the second child gets no $20$'s is 
$$\frac{\binom{5}{3}}{\binom{8}{3}}.$$
As before, this is $\frac{5}{28}$. So the required probability is $\frac{3}{28}$.

There are also decidedly more complicated ways to proceed. For instance, let $A$ be the event first bill drawn is a $10$, and let $B$ be the event the second envelope got no $20$'s. We find $\Pr(B|A)$, which is $\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(A)}$.

To find $\Pr(A)$, we could then divide into cases (i) first envelope got $1$ $10$ and the $10$ was on top; (ii) $2$ $10$'s, and a $10$ was on top; (iii) $3$ $10$'s. Not much fun.

Comment: Thank you very much! Amazing how you can make such a seemingly difficult question look so easy.

Comment: One question that I have though; why did you choose to count order also within the envelopes?

Comment: So as not to get into possible traps about what the first child had, she may have more than $1$ ten-dollar bill. This stuff is kind of delicate.

Comment: I feel slightly embarrassed to ask, but just out of general curiosity, could you please also show me how it would be done using binomial coefficients as you described in your remark (I am quite familiar with binomial coefficients)? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Not immediately, need to be away. But, particularly if no one else does it, I will write that way in roughly $5$ hours.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!